# Change formatting of date upon calling value

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms, form-control

On my frontend, I use an Angular (11) Material [Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) element to let the user pick a date. The formatting for this is done using the `MAT_DATE_LOCALE` provider, and it is `dd-MM-YYYY`, so 23-12-2020 for today. This Datepicker is linked to a [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) using reactive forms.

While I am content with how the date is represented to the user, I'd like to send the date in a `YYYY-MM-dd` format. It seems the Datepicker is setting the value of the FormControl to a Date object and I don't know if I can change this. I could of course create a method to change all the fields I need changed before POSTing, but this seems clumpy and I feel like it could be done more elegantly.

Comment: Material Datepicker is feed by defect by Date object of javascript, simply in your service transform the Date variables the method receive to a string before make the httpClient.post

Comment: @Eliseo that's actually already happening; I am getting them in JSON format and filling my FormControl with the result. If I then POST without modifying them, their type is `string`. Only once I change it using the Datepicker does it change to a Date object.

Comment: I try to explain the idea in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luctia, imagine we received some like

```
{
  name:'Name'
  birthdate:'1980-10-21'
}
```

You can has a service like

```
getData()
{
    return this.httpClient(...).pipe(map(x=>{
        x.birthdate=new Date(x.birthdate)
        return x
    })
}
//See that subscribing to the service in birthdate we has an object Date

getList(){
    return this.httpClient(...).pipe(map((list:any[])=>{
        list.forEach(x=>{
           x.birthdate=new Date(x.birthdate)
        })
        return list
    })
}
//see that when subcribing to List, return an array of object with birthdate is Date

updateData(data)
{
    //we calculate a birthdate string
    const birthdate=data.getFullYear()+'-'+
                   ('00'+(data.getMonth()+1).slice(-2)+'-'+
                   ('00'+data.getDate()).slice(-2)

    //send to post the data but the birthDate a string
    return this.httpClient.post(...,{...data,birthdate:birthdate})
}
```

Comment: I see what you meant now, this does make sense. Thanks!