# Date conversion to specific format using Angular pipes

Tags: angular, time

I have a column in sql table with ts as format:
this is the format I'm getting from database -

```
2020-12-07T08:02:00.000Z
```

I want this date to be converted in `DD/MM/YYYY, 2:00 P.M` format.

When I use the code below -

```
<span>{{ list.ts | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>
```

I'm getting `DD/MM/YYYY` format for date only, and when I use the code below -

```
<span>{{ list.ts | date: 'short'}}</span>
```

I'm getting output as -

```
MM/DD/YYYY, 2:00 P.M
```

What should we do in order to get the format as `DD/MM/YYYY, 2:00 P.M`.

Comment: check if you're receiving the "date" as string:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65430165/change-formatting-of-date-upon-calling-value/65431346#65431346

Comment: Okay thank you. i will check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass parameter to date pipe like this:

```
<p>
    {{ dateString | date:'dd/MM/YYYY hh:mm a' }}
</p>
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4qybsb?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Moment.js` and create pipe like

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'specialDate',
})
export class SpecialDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, format?: any): any {
    if (value) {
      return moment(value)
        .locale('en')
        .format(format ? format : 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a');
    } else return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could the same thing be implemented without `Moment.js`?