# Proper way to pass date objects between a javascript/typescript frontend and a ASP.net Core 5 backend

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, datetime

I'm developing a web application where the backend is a REST web API written in `ASP.net Core 5` and the frontend is an `Angular` application written in `TypeScript`.

One of my ASP.net backend APIs returns an instance of this C# object:

```
public class MyClass
{
  DateTime expires {get; set;}
  string ticket {get; set;}
}
```

In my Angular app, I call this API with Angular's `HTTP Client` and deserialize the result as an instance of the following TypeScript class:

```
export class MyClass
{
  expires: Date;
  ticket: string;
}
```

However, this doesn't work properly because because if I inspect the TypeScript object once it has been returned I can see that the `expires` field actually contains a `string`, not a Date object.

I imagine this happens because the data travels between backend and frontend in JSON format, which doesn't support types but only knows about strings and numbers, so the C# DateTime object is converted to a string.

My question is: what is the best way to handle this problem? I would like to keep my objects strongly typed if possible... is there some configuration I can do on the ASP.net and/or Angular side so that this kind of serialization works automatically? Or if not, what is the next best approach?

Comment: Which json converter do you use in back-end `NewtonSoft` or `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: It can't be done automatically because typescript type hints are kind of fake - you can't reflect on them at runtime like you can in C#, they don't exist at runtime. So angular can't know "expires" is actually date (json doesn't have a concept of date either). The best you can do is to manually convert, or when deserializing response - convert all strings that look like date to Date.

Comment: As Evk, say Angular always receive a string, you can use an approach like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65430165/change-formatting-of-date-upon-calling-value/65431346#65431346)

Comment: @AmirJabari: using the default for .NET 5, which I believe is `System.Text.Json`

Comment: Yes, you have to do it manually, the value of `expires` should look something like this `2021-11-12T18:52:59.0349748+00:00` you can use it like  `new Date('2021-11-12T18:52:59.0349748+00:00')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I put together from the suggested answers in the comments:

```
return this.http.get<MyClass>(restUrl, { observe: 'response' })
      .pipe(map(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          response.body.expires = new Date(response.body.expires);
          this.setLoginResult(response.body);
        }
        return response;
      }));
```